# How to store and retrieve data for use by HTML form?

Tags: php, html, database, forms, post

I'm working on a project I previously made for a hackathon, where users fill out an html form with demographic information to receive information about local services they may qualify for.

```
<form action = "resources.php" method = "post" class = "pure-form pure-form-stacked" id="mycounty">
            <h1>Resource Connection</h1>
            <h2>My County</h2>
            <h3>Age:</h3><input type="text" name = "age"><br>
            <h3>What is your gender?</h3>
            <select id = "gender" name = "gender">
                <option value="wom">Woman</option>
                <option value = "man">Man</option>
                <option value="nonb">Non-binary</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select><br>
            <label for="lowinc" class = "pure-checkbox">
                <input name="lowinc" type="checkbox" value="yes">
                Do you consider yourself to be low income?
            </label>
            <button type="submit" class="pure-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I used PHP during the hackathon for form handling and to store data about the resources and return it after the form is submitted, but now I'm trying to make it a useable website for clients of a friend in social work. I'm not sure if the way I'm currently storing data and using PHP is the best way to do this, or if I should use SQL or something else. I've dabbled with SQL in classes but I'm not sure if a mix of html, PHP, and SQL is the best way to do this either, it seems messy, so I'm looking for suggestions. I want to implement it for 3 different counties, and include resources like homeless shelters, afterschool programs, domestic violence resources, etc for each.

Here's an example of what's in the PHP file:

```
if($_POST["gender"] == "wom"){
        echo ("<br><h3>Compass Center for Women and Families</h3><h4>111 Example St, New York, NY 10001</h4>");
        echo '<a href="https://orgwebsite.org/" target="_blank"><h4>Website</h4></a>';
        echo '<p>Empowering individuals to navigate their journey of self-sufficiency, safety, and health.</p>';
        }
```

Comment: Storing data is the primary purpose of SQL.  MySQL and PHP go hand in hand with each other.

Answer (score 0):

A database (SQL or NoSQL) is the best way to store information. Here are a few reasons off the top of my head:

- Let everything do its job. Databases are designed to persist data. PHP is not.
- Changes are simple in a database, do you really want to make changes to data in the code?
- You can call database information from anywhere in the application. This also means you only have to edit data in one place.

There are many more reasons, but these are a few. You will thank yourself down the line if you switch to having your data in a database.